# Which one is correct: Browser Chrome, Chrome-Browser oder Chrome Browser?

Tags: word-choice, word-order

I am not sure about which version is correct. A Google search could not help.

```
Which option would you use and why?  
Are the others just less common or incorrect?
```

1. Browser Chrome
2. Chrome-Browser
3. Chrome Browser

The sentence would be "Wir mussten leider feststellen, dass der _______ einen Bug hat"

Comment: Technically, the name of the browser is [Google Chrome](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), so I'd consider using that. It'll probably depend on your target audience whether to add that it is a "browser" or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most common and correct is *Chrome-Browser*.

*der Browser Chrome* would also be possible. But it is rather formal and uncommon, would sound old-fashioned and maybe not even be considered correct.

*Chrome Browser* would widely be considered wrong. Traditionally, in German, [compound nouns are formed by glueing the compartiments together, sometimes with a hyphen](https://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Edeutsch/Grammatik/Wortbildung/Komposita.html). There is an anglicist trend of writing compounds like this, but it is still considered wrong by the most.

Answer (score 3):

The correct version is:

> Wir mussten leider feststellen, dass der Chrome-Browser einen Bug hat.

Here, we construct a compound from a browser further specified as Chrome.

Another possibility is:

> Wir mussten leider feststellen, dass der Browser "Chrome" einen Bug hat.

Here, we're adding the name to the abstract term, and that's why I used quotes to make that clear, as e.g. in *das Schiff "Titanic"*. Not absolutely necessary, as e.g. I'd write *die Stadt Duisburg* without the quotes.

*Der Chrome Browser* is wrong. The compound needs hyphenation.

But if I were to convey Chrome bug information, I'd write

> Wir mussten leider feststellen, dass Chrome Version 123.456 einen Bug hat.

Without a version reference, the information is useless. Bugs show up beginning with one version, and get fixed in a later version. And I omitted the word *Browser* as the audience of such a statement surely knows that Chrome is a browser.

Comment: FYI: never assume people know anything when it comes to technology. I know lots of people who are confused if you tell them "open the browser". Just saying

Comment: @E.V. (getting a bit off-topic) Is information about a Chrome bug useful for someone who doesn't know that Chrome is a browser? That was my line of reasoning.

Comment: "*The audience of such a statement surely knows that Chrome is a browser.*" - actually the term "Chrome" is used for a few [other things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome#Computing) that could have software bugs. So it really depends on the context whether it's clear that you refer to the browser or not.